# How could I make desktop application to trigger selenium test in MStest?

Tags: wpf, selenium-webdriver, mstest

I am asked to write an desktop application to trigger selenium automation test, My testing framework is MSTest and installed selenium from nuget.

I googled around but can not find articles about how to do it. Since I am a little familiar with .NET( than any other backend framework), Should I use WPF to trigger my selenium test?

I understand how to run my selenium project from command line, I build my project and take the bin folder out, write a Powershell to run it. (dotnet test run) And it successes, **but I have no idea how to make it become a desktop application that I can input different arguments to run my test.**

Please help. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver is generally run inside a unit test framework, ideally NUnit 3 (in my opinion)

There is a bit of setup for the structure, which is a lot more that would fit in this answer box